# How to populate html table with json object contents

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, html-table

I am returning a list in a ajax call the success function is written below.
My json has contents like {"1","ayesha","cs","Lahore"}.

```
 function ShowData(data) {
         var data = data.d;

        var html = "";
        if (data.length > 0) {
            JObject = data;
            console.log(JObject);
            html = "<table id='tbl' class='TableGrid'  width='100%' >";
            html += "<thead><tr><th>StdId</th><th>Name</th><th>feild</th><th>City</th></thead><tbody> ";
            for (var i = 0; i < JObject.length; i++) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += ' <td align="left" >' + JObject[i] + '</td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            }
            html += "</tbody> </table>";

        }
```

How should i display the contents?

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow script can help to create table

1. var table = document.createElement("table");
2. var thead = document.createElement("thead");
3. var tr = document.createElement("tr");
4. var th = document.createElement("th");
5. var td = document.createElement("td");
6. table.appendChild(thread).appendChild(th);
7. table.appendChild(tr).appendChild(td)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.innerHTML` to insert your table inside your template.

DOCS: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp